# I'm not sure about this くらいで

Tags: translation, meaning, particle-くらい

> 「恋愛成就のお守りを託されたくらいで、自己改革が出来る程度のものだったとは思えないの。」

What purpose does くらいで serve in this sentence? How would you translate it?

Comment: How would **you** translate it?

Comment: I have no idea. Maybe で acts as から?

Answer (score 1):

> 「恋愛成就{れんあいじょうじゅ}のお守{まも}りを託{たく}された**くらいで**、自己改革{じこかいかく}が出来{でき}る程度{ていど}のものだったとは思{おも}えないの。」

If this were a written sentence, I would simply ask its author to rewrite it as it is not very clearly written. The 「思えないの」 ending, however, suggests that it is a ***spoken*** line, so I will try not to sound too judgy here.

Unless the larger context proves otherwise, the 「～～くらいで」 should describe how trivial, unimportant, etc. the preceding part (~~) is in comparison to what follows.  Using the actual words, here is the structure of this "sentence".

"恋愛成就のお守りを託された was all that happened (which is quite trivial since a love charm is a hit-or-miss kind of thing) and I still do not think that it was 自己改革が出来る程度のもの."

> "Sure, a love charm was left in my keeping, but who could have thought that it would be as super-effective as to make you accomplish self-reform? (Not me!)"

Comment: @l'électeurSo くらいで works as one grammar? It is not くらい + で?

Comment: It is くらい + で. で can be used to mean "because" or "by way of."

Comment: I see. Then, what about くらい? I don't understand its role here.